# How to arrange images with coordinates given from xml?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

Good day, I have a question. I need to use loop to arrange loaded images from XML. How should I load   in function loadData  images with it's coordinates(x,y) and description with textfields ?? Here is my code:

```
var xmlList:XMLList;
var urlLoader:URLLoader;
function Main():void 
    {
        urlLoader = new URLLoader();
        urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("images.xml"));
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadData);


    }
function loadData(e:Event):void {

xml = new XML(urlLoader.data);
xmlList = xml.image;
for (var i:uint = 0; i < xmlList.length(); i ++ ) 
    {

   }}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<images>
<image>
    <title>First Picture</title>
    <file>images/pic1.jpg</file>
    <x>180</x>
    <url></url>
    <y>50</y>       
</image>
<image>
    <title>Second Picture</title>
    <file>images/pic2.jpg</file>
    <x>100</x>
    <y>100</y>
    <url></url>     
</image>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code I would suggest you to use a TileList to display the images.
Than, you can build a custom component to use as itemRenderer in order to get the result you
want.
Even if you don't want to use a list to display the images, you will have to create a custom component so you can display the image + text and use the XY attributes of your component to position it on the screen.

It would be basically like this:

`
    var myComp:MyCustomComponent;

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < xmlList.length(); i ++ ) 
{
   myComp = new MyCustomComponent();
   targetUI.addChild(myComp);
   myComp.text = xmlList..image[i].title;
   myComp.imgsrc = xmlList..image[i].file;
   myComp.x = xmlList..image[i].x;
   myComp.y = xmlList..image[i].y;
}
```

`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You must in function loadData create new Loaders for images

```
function loadData():void
{
     var imageLoader:Loader;
     for (var i:int = 0; i < xmlList.length();i++)
     {
          imageLoader = new Loader();
          imagePath:URLRequest = new URLRequest(xmlList[i].file);
          imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.Complete, loadCompleteHandler);
          imageLoader.load(imagePath);
}
function loadCompleteHandler(event:Eent):void
{
    var loaderInfoParams:LoaderInfo = event.currentTarget as LoaderInfo;
    var currentImage:Bitmap = event.currentTarget.content as Bitmap;

    addChild(currentImage);
}
```

After that, use loaderInfoParams.url find the name of loaded image. And, use name of loaded image in xml find others parameters. Or you can create a Dictionary, there the key is image name, and the value is coordinates and text.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting an error - "URL is not found", where is the mistake?

Comment: check imagePath:URLRequest = new URLRequest(xmlList[i].file); Error say, that there is no image in path xmlList[i].file

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! And I have one more question.. How could I draw frame for this pictures(linestyle)? Standard way in this case doesn't work.

Comment: Paste the code. In LoadComplete function put you image in Sprite, and in sprite draw frame .

Comment: I've done it in loadData function: var imageHolder:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); imageHolder.addChild(imageLoader);////images appeared but imageHolder doesn't draw frame by method -  imageHolder.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000,1);

Comment: imageHolder.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000,1) - this method don't draw line, he sets the properties. Use imageHolder.graphics.moveTo() and imageHolder.graphics.lineTo() methods to draww line.